# Argument error when trying to call C++ extension as an external process

Tags: python, c++, boost-python

Currently, I am calling an extended C++ module from Go.

The problem is not in Go but the way the data structure is designed to call the python function

**Note:**

```
(1) This cfolder (with .cpp) is C++ extension 
(2) The main.py calls .cpp via Python runtime
(3) I am reproducing main.py in Go (calling cfolder directly from Go)
```

**Existing Python file : main.py**

```
class Pkeys(object):
    key1 = 0x6B
    key2 = 0xDA2
    defkey = {'0xffff':None}

class Trp(object):
   def __init__(self, hdd, **kwargs):

   self.uname = hdd
//This is accessing the class defined under networkHeads.py
   self.__cfolder = cfolder.Trp(hdd, networkHeads.getTcpProto, Pkeys, kwargs)
        
   @property
    def get_location(self):
        print("Getting Location Data...")
        return self.__cfolder.UDS  
  //This is accessing a function under .cpp file
```

**File :** networkHeads.py

```
def getTcpProto(trp):
```

**Folder** : cfolder
**File** : cfolder.cpp

Trp::Trp(string d, object tcpTables, object _keys, dict kwargs) :

> class Trp "Trp(drivePath, TcpTables, Keys, kwargs)"

```
#include <boost/python/module.hpp>
#include <boost/python/def.hpp>

static const char * TrpDocs =
Trp::Trp(string ssd, object TcpTables, object Keys, dict kwargs) :

Trp::~Trp() {
 }

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(cfolder)
{
   class_<Trp>("Trp", TrpDocs, init<string, object, object, dict>())
            .add_property("UDS",                &Trp::getUDS,               udsDocs);
 }

$python3
>>import cfolder
>>func = cfolder.Trp.            
cfolder.Trp.UDS                 cfolder.Trp.temp
```

From Go, I am trying to call Trp().UDS

```
func CallUDS(dd string) {
    
_,err1 := os.Open(dd)

if err1 != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Cannot %s\n",err1)
    os.Exit(1)
}
cmd:= exec.Command("python3", "-c", "import cfolder; cfolder.Trp().UDS")
```

When I build the project, I get this error

```
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    Trp.__init__(str, NoneType, NoneType, NoneType)
did not match C++ signature:
    __init__(_object*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, boost::python::api::object, boost::python::api::object, boost::python::dict)
```

I don't have the right to change any files under *cfolder*.

Rather I try to create arguments in such a way that it can call the UDS undet Trp().

1. How and where the changes needs to be applied?
2. What is exactly causing this error?

Comment: C++, Python, Go -- I wonder if you couldn't reduce this, in order to get closer to a [mcve]. Further, it lacks quite some code. Also, tag this question with `boost` while you're at it. However, search for the error ("Boost.Python.ArgumentError argument types did not match signature") online and I think you will find some info.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, I did refer to such similar posts before posting. Since I dont have access to change the original c++ files but rather find a way to call them from Go code, I had to post this question. I will edit my question to expose more of the codes. Thanks for the suggestion